# Extra optional classname in a component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class-names

I'm using classnames to add many classes to a React component. In my button I want to have the opportunity to add a class to the component if I want to, it should be optional.

But I get a type error, see attached image [image]

How can I get rid of the error?

*Button code*

```
import classnames from "classnames";
import styles from "./button.module.css";

interface ButtonProps {
    children: JSX.Element;
    onClick: () => void;
    small?: boolean;
    className?: string;
}

function Button({ onClick, children, small, className }: ButtonProps) {
    return (
        <button
            className={classnames(styles.button, {
                [styles.small]: small,
                [className]: !!className,
            })}
            onClick={onClick}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

*and the error:*

`A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)`

Comment: You are casting it to a boolean with `!!`. Why?

Comment: Since `className` prop is optional its type is `string | undefined` which conflicts with the typing of an object's property name. Either make `className` mandatory or change the code to only add the property when it's actually defined.

Comment: If `className` is not defined then you will end up with an object property like `{"undefined": false}` where the computed property name `undefined` has been coerced to a string.  The TypeScript compiler assumes that's an error.  If you *want* this to happen (unlikely) you should do `[String(className)]: !!className]`.  If you *don't* want this to happen (likely) you should do something like a conditional spread

Answer (score 0):

Your `className` is used as a property name even though it might be undefined. Note that an optional `string` is really a `string | undefined`. I would use object spread to accomplish conditionality.

The new argument to classnames function:

```
{
  [styles.small]: small,
  ...(typeof className === 'string' ?
    { [className]: true } :
    {}
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly something like this I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If the condition for forwarding your `props.className` is only `!!props.className`, then you can forward them directly as an argument passed to `classnames()`:

```js
classnames(styles.button, props.className, {
  [styles.small]: props.small,
})
```

If you want to interject logic beyond `!!props.className`, you can add it as the **first check** of `&&`:

```js
const forwardedClass = !!getComplexValue() && props.className; // Order is important

classnames(styles.button, forwardedClass, {
  [styles.small]: small,
})
```

---

Examples:

```js
classnames('button-class', undefined, {
  'small-class': false
})
// 'button-class'

classnames('button-class', 'foobar w-full', {
  'small-class': true
})
// 'button-class foobar w-full small-class'

classnames('button-class', false && 'foobar w-full', {
  'small-class': false
})
// 'button-class'
```

⚠️ Order is important:

```js
classnames(
  'button-class',
  {
    'small-class': false, // <-- About to be overwritten
  },
  true && 'small-class' // <-- Overwrites previous check
);
// 'button-class small-class'
```